# Download doesn't work in Firefox recently

Tags: firefox

My current Firefox version is 9.0.1. I am under Ubuntu 10.10. I am not sure if some recent updates has changed Firefox, but

1. its appearance has changed:

   - its tab bar has been moved above address bar, and
   - the original fresh and stop buttons  beside the backward/forward    buttons have been combined and moved into one single small button
     within the address bar.
2. The worst thing is that right click and then "save link as", for
   example for downloading pdf and other documents, will become
   unresponsive a short while after starting the Firefox.  **Added:**
   My problem is with right-click download, and sometimes even those
   pop out download ( I mean paste a link to a pdf file in address bar
   and hit return). In these cases, I can choose where to save files
   to, but after that nothing is downloaded. Restarting Firefox may
   solve the problem, but that is certainly not the solution.

I was wondering why and how to fix the download problem? And possibly change back to original appearance of the Firefox?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Sounds like you've been upgraded to the latest version, and those changes are what I have in my 9.0.1 version for Ubuntu 11.10.  I have noticed occasionally that the right click menu stops working correctly, and disappears immediately, but a restart fixed it.  But if the link is for a download,  can you  left click on it? It's not clear whether your problem is related to downloading or right-clicking.

Comment: My problem is with right-click download, and sometimes even those pop out download ( I mean paste a link to a pdf file in address bar and hit return). In this cases, I can choose where to save files to, but after that nothing is downloaded. Restarting Firefox may solve the problem, but that is certainly not the solution.

Comment: I'll take the easy part of the question. View/Toolbars/Tabs on top (uncheck it). I haven't a clue what the rest of the issues are though, sorry.

Comment: @TomBrossman: Thanks! That solved the easy part. About the rest, do you not understand the rest, or do but don't have solution?

Comment: I understand your descriptions, I just have no idea what's wrong. If it was me I'd back up my bookmarks, then delete my .mozilla folder and try starting over. Sometimes this is simpler than tracing an obscure problem.

Comment: @TomBrossman: How do you back up your Firefox bookmarks?

Comment: Probably a good idea about the profile, although you can also create a new profile and later delete the old one if needed, using the profile manager - see [Managing Profiles](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles) for instructions.

Comment: Other questions: if you go to the download manager (in Tools=>Downloads), does the file show up as being downloaded?  Also, if not, is it possible you're saving it to a directory where you don't have write permission (a long shot, but thought I'd ask)?  Sometimes problems have unexpected reasons, so it's good to try everything.

Comment: @Marty: No, the file does not show up as being downloaded in the download manager. I have permission to write the directory.

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced exactly the same problem with downloading. I solved it by:

- going to the menu  Edit>Preferences>General, then select "Save file to Downloads" and [Close].
- After that you can try to download something to the default directory at least once. If it works, then go to the same dialog and set it back  to the other option, i.e. "Always aske me...".

I would guess there is something broken in the settings registry of Firefox, and by forcing this setting change, the respective entry gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't work for me. I think my problem is because the path of the directory for saving the downloaded file is a string that is too long to be handled by download manager of Firefox. But for saving webpages directly in Firefox, it works fine with long path

Comment: Hi Tim, this sounds like a bug, there should be no length limit. If I were you, I would try to submit this as a bug on Mozilla bug tracker

Comment: Had similar problem, turns out my user didn't have write permission to "Downloads" folder and that resulted in immediate failure.
I'll try to report this bug to mozilla